# Generating PDB files correctly for a native DLL using Visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, pdb-files

Yesterday, I went through our company's projects and updated them to fix a mistake (AFAIK) in how we configured them.

The issue was that under the property pages for the projects, under `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Output Files`, we set `Program Database File Name` to `$(OutDir)$(TargetName).pdb`, the *same* value we had set `Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Debugging -> Generate Program Database File`.

My understanding is that the first property sets the location of the pdb file which contains symbols for the object files created during compilation of the source, while the second sets the location of the pdb file which contains symbols for the generated DLL. Is that correct?

Under this assumption, to prevent them from conflicting (I assume this is unwanted) I set the first property to `$(IntDir)$(TargetName).pdb`, but this broke the resulting pdb file (i.e. a debugger doesn't recognize it as the DLL's pdb file, and a co-worker ran a tool on it, and the signature does not match the one contained in the binary).

The strange thing is that using the value `$(IntDir)$(TargetName)2.pdb` (note the '2' suffix) fixes the issue. I don't understand why the name of the intermediate file would matter?

Note that `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Debug Information Format` is set to `Program Database (/Zi)`

Comment: the symbols for current module are contained in the file: Linker -> Debugging ->Generate Program Database File. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwx19e36(v=vs.120).aspx)

This what you should be using during debugging.

Comment: Microsoft made a mistake a long, long time ago, the kind they can never fix.  That .pdb file is not intended for the debugger and does not contain debug info.   The compiler uses it to keep track of builds, meant to speed up subsequent builds.  Changing the setting is not useful.

Comment: Which one, the one under linker, or the one under c++? Do you have any link to relevant documentation?

Answer (score 4):

I'd say you got it right: the compiler produces object files. At that time the DLL is not ready yet, so whatever that PDB file contains, it's not helpful in debugging.

After the linker has processed the output of the compiler, the DLL exists. At that time, a PDB makes sense for debugging. So the relevant file for debugging purposes is in `Linker -> Debugging -> Generate Program Database File`.

As @HansPassant mentioned in the comments, the Compiler setting should not be touched. Too bad it already happened. In a Visual Studio 2013 or 2015 C++ console application, the default value for `C/C++ -> Output Files` is `$(IntDir)vc$(PlatformToolsetVersion).pdb`, so the final name is something like `Debug\vc120.pdb` or `Debug\vc140.pdb`.

IMHO, changing the compiler's output file should not matter, as long as the name does not conflict with the linker setting. That's exactly what happened to you: the compiler name `$(IntDir)$(TargetName).pdb` (relative path) resolves to the same file  as the linker name `$(OutDir)$(TargetName).pdb` (absolute path). In that case it may happen that the linker cannot write to the file because it's still in use by the compiler or other strange things.

Comment: @Bwmat: I don't think it should matter. But I've actually never tried that. The only name you should definitely not use is `$(IntDir)$(TargetName).pdb`, since that creates a name collision with the linker output file.

Comment: @Bwmat: added that to the answer

Comment: But it shouldn't create a collision, the linker one goes in outdir while the other goes in intdir.

Comment: @Bwmat: in a new C++ solution from scratch on my machine, IntDir is relative and OutDir is absolute directory but referring to the same directory.